# ion-datetime displayFormat how to escape literals in ionic4?

Tags: ionic4

I want to have time like `14h 32m`. My code:

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="HH(h) mm(m)" placeholder="Set Duration">
</ion-datetime>
```

But ionic treats (h) and (m) as hours and minutes and I have in result: `14(2) 32(32)`.

Answer (score 0):

well you can put this HH:mm and you should get this 14:32. I don't really know if you can put behind hours or minuts.

Comment: No. question is: how to escape literals. for example momentjs make it is this way - `moment().format('h[h]')` - square braces.
Meaning - I need `14h 32m` not `14:32`